# How to implement multi threading in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, multithreading

https://www.npmjs.com/package/threads

It seems to me we can use this package in Angular for running threads.
But I feel difficulties on implementing this.
Is there anyway to use threading in Angular?
How can I use thread in Angular?

Comment: I think we can use rxjs's forkjoin.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Angular does not have "threads", which by the way can mean many different things, in different contexts, environments, platforms, CPUs, and operating systems. Threads can be a way to accomplish parallelism; or they can be a way to organize your code as a set of concurrent processes; or they can be a way to manage access to shared resources; or any or all of the above.

Angular works in a browser. Browsers run JavaScript. The closest thing we have to threads in our browser world is **web workers**. To greatly oversimplify, web workers are not light-weight threads; in other words, you wouldn't want to create 100,000 of them. But if you are looking for a simple way to offload some computation away from the main browser task, so that it does not lock up the browser while you are computing, then you are probably interested in web workers.

Web workers do not really need any special library, or wrapping, or scaffolding. They're easy enough to just write directly. However, if you're interested in some ways to facilitate the process of using web workers within an Angular context, then google for "angular web workers".

I have no special knowledge of the library you mention. At first glance, it appears to be a way to abstract concurrent algorithms over different threading implementations appropriate for the node.js platform vs. the browser. If you're planning on working in Angular, then most likely the node.js platform part is irrelevant, so this entire library is not anything you should be interested in.

Comment: Hi, @torazaburo. Thanks for your kind reply. If I have to use web worker then how can I implement it?

Comment: @artgb By following any of the many tutorials and intros available everywhere on the web.