# Call WebAPI method in thread

Tags: typescript, thread-safety, angular7, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an `Angular7` client application which consumes a webAPI. I want to call a webAPI method again and again, and I want to display the output of that API method call on UI on each call.

If I do this using a while loop I won't be able to display continuously and the application will get hang. So decided to do this with thread but I don't know how to implement thread in `TypeScript`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use thread in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237613/use-thread-in-angular-5)

Comment: You should be using the rxjs library and using Subsriptions. Have a look here: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `setInterval()` to call the api repeatedly  and `clearInterval()` to stop it.For example,

```
startTimer() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.http.get<WeatherForecast[]>('https://localhost:44360/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts').subscribe(result => {
      //do things
    }, error => console.error(error));
}, 1000)//repeat every sceond

pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Refer to [How to do a timer in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455347/how-to-do-a-timer-in-angular-5), 
[Angular 6 - run method is service every 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585764/angular-6-run-method-is-service-every-10-seconds)

Comment: Nice \o/. it's working. this what I am looking for thanks @Xing Zou :-)